# Defining an objects name and description as variables in a function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a function for my lookup process as it looks like I'm going to need to use it a lot. I swapped out the parts to make it versatile except it seems to have trouble finding the "property" you define now I've modified it. I believe `lookupResult[array[i][property]` is the problem as I'm not sure how to change it for the function (it was `pINV[i].id` before). Can anyone offer any solutions?

```js
var pINV = [];
var examine = "ball"; // What the player typed (for simplicity)

function Item(id, desc) {
  this.id = id;
  this.desc = desc;
}

function Lookup(array, property) {
  var lookupResult = {};
  for (var i = 0, len = [array].length; i < len; i++) {
    lookupResult[array[i][property]] = array[i];
  }
  return lookupResult;
}

var invLookup = Lookup(pINV, id);
var item = invLookup[examine];
console.log(item.desc);
```

Comment: Send the property name as a string `Lookup(pINV, "id")`

Comment: was `id` supposed to be passed as a string?  Right now `property` will be undefined in your `Lookup` method because `id` is undefined when you pass it to `Lookup`

Answer (score 1):

Well this `[array].length` is wrong. It is doing [[1,2,3]] instead of [1,2,3] so the length is always going to be one. Drop the `[]`